# Aggregate/sum/tally values based on identical column names or separate df in R

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I've been trying to do this several different ways, (aggregate, colSum, tally, etc) but am struggling.

I have a large data set of sample results (100 columns, 1,000,000 rows), where I have replaced the individual sample names with the name of the category they belong to. (I need to tally the totals for each data point by category.

```
Sequence   position  cat1  cat1  cat2  cat2  cat2  cat3  cat3
abfsgdfy   a         0     1     0     1     0     1     1
abfsgdfy   b         0     0     1     1     1     1     0
dgdtecgd   b         1     1     1     0     0     0     0
```

I understand that it isn't desirable to have identical column names, so I've been attempting to transpose the data, and then work with it. But that hasn't gotten me very far either.

The output I'm looking for would be along the lines of:

```
Sequence  position  cat1  cat2  cat3
abfsgdfy   a        1     1     2 
abfsgdfy   b        0     3     1
dgdtecgd   b        2     1     0
```

If it helps, I have a table that translates the sample names to the larger category group:

```
Type    Name
cat1    sample1
cat1    sample2
cat2    sample3
cat2    sample4
cat2    sample5
cat3    sample6
cat3    sample7
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
library("tidyverse")
df = tibble(c("abfsgdfy", "abfsgdfy", "dgdtecgd"),
                c("a", "b", "b"),
                c(0, 0, 1),
                c(1, 0, 1),
                c(0, 1, 1),
                c(1, 1, 0),
                c(0, 1, 0))
colnames(df) = c("Sequence", "position", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2")

# rename column names to make them unique:
newcols = c("Sequence", "position", paste0("c", 1:(ncol(df)-2)))
oldcols = colnames(df)
colnames(df) = newcols

# make a crosswalk
col_cross = tibble(oldcols = oldcols,
                   newcols = newcols)

# gather the new columns, summarize across the old columns, spread
df %>% 
  gather(key = "newcols", value = "val", -Sequence, -position) %>% 
  left_join(col_cross) %>% 
  group_by(Sequence, position, oldcols) %>% 
  summarize(n = sum(val)) %>% 
  spread(key = oldcols, value = n, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Your script as is works, but when putting it against my own data, it regurgitates the original table, but with the category names changed to sample names changed to c1, c2, c3, etc.

Comment: Hmmm that's not really enough information for me to help further. Does the col_cross data set look right with your data? Are there any messages that come from the dplyr statements?

Comment: Sorry, doing too many things at once. I believe it is because my data has the column names already, but you are referencing colnames(df) to save the old naming structure. I don't have a fixed column name structure because it changes depending on the file I am looking at.
(I keep posting on accident - not well versed in posting here.)
I am trying the following:
oldcols = colnames(df)
newcols = c("locus", "strand", paste0("c", 1:(ncol(df)-2)))
colnames(df) = newcols

It takes about 10 minutes for it to run,

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty sure my method will work. You may want to sit down and slowly go through it with a fresh R session. Make sure you change the object names in my method to whatever you loaded your data in as. I also did not provide an assignment statement at the end. Good luck

Comment: It worked great! Like you said, I didn't have an assignment statement so it was outputting junk. Added an assignment and it makes the table I need. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A different `tidyverse` possibility:

```
repair_names(df, prefix = "cat", sep = "_") %>% 
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -c(Sequence, position, rowid)) %>%
 mutate(temp = sub("\\_.*", "", var)) %>%
 arrange(rowid) %>%
 group_by(Sequence, position, temp) %>%
 summarise(res = sum(val),
           rowid = first(rowid)) %>%
 spread(temp, res) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  Sequence position  cat1  cat2
  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 abfsgdfy a           1.    1.
2 abfsgdfy b           0.    3.
3 dgdtecgd b           2.    1.
```

First, it changes the the columns names to have a `"cat"` prefix and `"_"` as a separator. Second, it transforms the data from wide to long format. Third, using `sub("\\_.*", "", var)` it takes the strings before the `"_"`. Then, it sums the values. Finally, it returns the data to wide format.

Using the sample data provided by @svenhalvorson:

```
df <- tibble(c("abfsgdfy", "abfsgdfy", "dgdtecgd"),
            c("a", "b", "b"),
            c(0, 0, 1),
            c(1, 0, 1),
            c(0, 1, 1),
            c(1, 1, 0),
            c(0, 1, 0))
colnames(df) <- c("Sequence", "position", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2")
```

Comment: Sorry for the generics, I don't actually use cat1, cat2, etc. It could be Square, Turtle, Ball, Blue, 55, etc.
But I could make a translation file that assigns them generic cat1, cat2, etc and test this. (I'll try it tomorrow most likely.)

Comment: Then you can replace the first row with `repair_names(df, sep = "_")`.

Comment: This works as well! Thanks!  I'll have to time these two solutions and see how they compare.

Comment: It takes 3.94 minutes to run Sven's code, and 4.63 to run yours.